# Adding Html and with accordion to Product tab woocommerce

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

Adding HTML and with accordion to Product tab woocommerce.But i cannot see panel drop down.Checked code m i making any mistake here.for HTML all results should individually displayed in table.all codes in child theme

```
     //This goes in child theme function

 $result = '<div class="custom" >';

 if( ! empty( $Brand) )
     $result .= '<p>'. __('<table class="custom"><span id="si" ><button class="accordion">Brand</button></span> ').'<span id="si1" ><div class="panel">
 <p>'.$Brand.'</p>
  </div>
   </span></table></p>';

 button.accordion {
     background-color: #eee;
     color: #444;
     cursor: pointer;
     padding: 18px;
     width: 100%;
     border: none;
     text-align: left;
     outline: none;
     font-size: 15px;
     transition: 0.4s;
 }

 button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
     background-color: #ccc; 
 }

 div.panel {
     padding: 0 18px;
     display: none;
     background-color: white;
 }  

   //This goes in child theme function

 ?>
 <script>
 var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
 var i;

 for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
     acc[i].onclick = function(){
         this.classList.toggle("active");
         var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
         if (panel.style.display === "block") {
             panel.style.display = "none";
         } else {
             panel.style.display = "block";
         }
     }
 }
 </script>
 <?php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made some mistake in html `table` you didnt add `tr` so all data will come out from `table` And I made correction on your code so it will work effectively.

Change those PHP code as following

```
if( ! empty( $select ) )
{
    $output .= '
    <div class="woo-acc">
        <ul>
            <li class="acc-tit"><span>Brand Name </span> <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i><br>
                <div class="acc-cont">'.$select.'</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>';
}
```

In css change replace with following code

```
.woo-acc ul { list-style: none; margin-left: 0px; }
.acc-tit i{font-size: 12px;font-weight: 100;}
.acc-cont{display: none;}
.acc-tit:hover > i:before { content: ""; }
.acc-tit:hover .acc-cont { display: block; }
```

Hope it will help... If you have any issue post back...

Comment: Worked Perfectly Thanks